# When debugging, how do I launch the same EXE twice for a P2P app?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, network-programming

I'm making a P2P application and need to launch the same P2P exe two times (as I can't separate the client from the server.

Is there any way to make the same EXE launch twice, with the debugger?

Or is there a better way I should architect the application?

Comment: Just launch one from the command line and debug from the other. Or launch VS twice. You certainly shouldn't need to debug both at the same time.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson What I'm trying to step through is the interaction between each exe.  Your dual instance of VS2013 is great.  Thanks

Comment: Taking a wild guess here, but lack of unit tests???

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yup, no Unit Test, just mocking up a quick demo. Not sure how to make that happen.  Have any tips?

Comment: Depends if you are writing it all then write some of the unit tests. Better still go test build test and iterate. Like a shout out you are here, and a listen for available clients. Then request and accept a connection, then the actual communications. Off the shelf components / code would be different and almost certainly quicker.